# issue with counting lines of python file

Tags: python, file

I am traversing a directory, and if python file is found, trying to find the number of lines of code in it.
I am not really sure why I face the below issue.

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(APP_FOLDER):

    for file in filenames:
        if pathlib.Path(file).suffix == ".py":
            num_lines = len(open(file).readlines()) #causes issue
            print(
                f"Root:{dirpath}\n"
                f"file:{file}\n\n"
                f"lines: {num_lines}" //
            )
```

Érror:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    num_lines = len(open(file).readlines())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

If i remove that line, the code works as expected. There is a single line code within. Any guidance here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this way. You have to get the `os.path.abspath(file)` path of the file then only it'll open.

and always with `contect_managers` for IO operation.

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(APP_FOLDER):
    for file in filenames:
        if pathlib.Path(file).suffix == ".py":
            try:
                with open(os.path.abspath(file)) as f:
                    print(len(f.readlines()))
                    print(os.path.abspath(file))
            except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 3):

`file` is the file's name, not its path, to get its full path, join the name with the directory path `dirpath` using `os.path.join`. Also, it is better to use a `with` statement when dealing with files since it automatically closes the file:

```
file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, file)

with open(file_path) as f:
    num_lines = len(f.readlines())
```